# Vuetify v-btn outlined property change dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have vuetify button.

```
<v-btn class="ma-2" tile :outlined="is_outlined" color="success">
    <v-icon left>mdi-pencil</v-icon> Edit
</v-btn>
```

I want to change its outlined property programmatically. I try like this:

> :outlined="is_outlined"     // variable
>   :outlined="is_outlined()"   // method

and them don't work.

Can I do it? How?

Answer (score 0):

`:outlined="isOutlined"` attribute should get a `true` or `false` value:

```js
computed: {
  isOutlined () {
    // Specify condition here:
    if (condition1) {
      return true
    }
    else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer, but sorry, it doesn't work. On enter yes, but it isn't after button click which changes condition

Comment: @ZenKos what condition do you have? Can you edit your answer and add the code that you are talking about?

Comment: I break project and recompile it, and it start work! Thank you so much. Many regards.

Comment: @ZenKos glad I could help